# Interfacing with a LabJack

Tags: interoperability, hardware

I have a [LabJack U3-HV](http://labjack.com/u3) and I wanted to use it with *Mathematica* to interface some hardware. I cannot find any information on the Internet; if I have to use Python, I will, but I would rather use *Mathematica*. Does anyone have any advice on this?

Specifically, I can't figure out how to read "AIN0" (the LabJack's first analog input) using *Mathematica*.

Comment: Nice idea. I think you'll have to write the interface to the device yourself using the provided C/.NET/Java libraries and either LibraryLink, NETLink, or JLink as appropriate. A lot of information is provided [here](http://labjack.com/support/ud/software-options/programming-ud).

Comment: Perhaps [this link](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/15734/streaming-data-into-mathematica-from-a-serial-port) may give you some insight into grabbing serial port data.

Comment: FWIW, the LabJack is not a serial port device; one must link with its own library to get access to its inputs and outputs. I haven't got one to try it myself, but the procedure for getting it working in *Mathematica* will be pretty much the same as shown for IGOR or MATLAB in the link I posted above. I think there is more than enough information there to get it going.